# What determines a lightsaber's length?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

The blade (for want of a better term) length does not appear to be standard.  I remember an expanded universe story featuring a character using lightsaber with an incredibly long reach, and let us not forget Yoda's teeny tiny lightsaber.

Is the length determined by the user, or does it's design determine the blade length?

Comment: As the lightsabers are not freely interchangeable (as both the color and length suggest that the same person only wields their own lightsaber); it seems most likely that a lightsaber is tailor made to its wielder. So that would mean it depends on the wielder's physical properties, personal preferences, and potentially their preferred combat style.

Comment: As I recall, the length was adjustable, although most Jedi didn't put a [length adjuster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber#Mechanics) on their saber.

Comment: Its mass divided by density. Radius was approximately constant.

Comment: Mass / Density = Volume, not Length, but nevermind. Since answers to the linked question confirm that the length of a Lightsaber is dependant solely on the construction of the saber itself, I agree that this can be closed as a dupe. It's a bit of a loose dupe, though.

Comment: Matter, size does not.

Comment: Actually, I believe the blade length depends on the wielder's [Schwartz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjVatNQr-GM)

Comment: I don't know about you, but I hate getting my Schwartz twisted.